# Edit return value in a class without modifying the class itself?

Tags: java

Okay, so let's say I have a class called Pancake.

Pancake.java would look something like this:

```
public class Pancake {
    public boolean shouldEat() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, I don't want to edit Pancake.java at all.  All I want to do is to change what `shouldEat()` returns to from a different class, such as "NotPancake.java".

I know if I had something like

```
public boolean eat = false;
```

I could easily just change that by doing something like `Pancake.eat = true`, but is there any way of changing what `shouldEat()` returns to without editing the class in a similar way?

Thanks.

Comment: Look into aspects and aspect oriented programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to do that is based on [Object Oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

```
public class NotPancake extends Pancake {

 @Override
 public boolean shouldEat() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The magic that happens here is called "inheritance," and is one of four elements assigned to OO.

What happens here is that you define new structure that is delivered from Pancake.

This means that `NotPancake` inherits form `Pancake`. So a NotPancake is a Pancake.

```
 Pancake p = new Pancake();
 Pancake q = new NoPancake(); 

 print(p.shouldEat()); //Will be false
 print(q.shouldEat()); //Will be true
```

This relation gives us the possibility to change the behavior, we are allowed to redefine all public, protected and defaults methods from super class.

The when in our child class we define a method with the same signature we say that this method override the previous one. In Java you should add the annotation `@Override` to inform compiler additionally about it.

This is one way to do it. The inheritance is simple but create a lot of issue in coding complex programs an alternative solution is called [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition). and you should always prefer composition over inheritance.

The composition is based on the abstractness. To use it a `interface` is required. The interface is an description of an contract that classes that implements it follow.

```
public interface Dish {

   boolean isEatable();

}
```

The name of interface should represent some abstract general concept.

```
 public class Pancake implements Dish {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldEat() {
     return false;
  }
}

public class Carrot implements Dish {

 @Override
 public boolean shouldEat() {
     return true;
  }
}
```

Usage is more less the same.

```
 Dish dish1 = new Pancake();
 Dish dish2 = new NoPancake(); 

 print(dish1.shouldEat()); //Will be false
 print(dish2.shouldEat()); //Will be true
```

On this small example is hard to show the benefits for composition. But is demonstrate the [coding to interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) approach.

Comment: So there's no other way to do this without inheritance?

Comment: You have two ways, with inheritance or with the interface. The interfaces is not a must in this case but show an alternative path. In term of your limitation you may want to choose the first method.

Answer (score 3):

```
Pancake p = new Pancake() {
   public boolean shouldEat() {
      return true;
   }
 };
```

Comment: Which is an anonymous subclass.

Comment: Yep.  Vash's way is using a first class Class (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function#Java).  Mine uses an instance of an anonymous class.  Both are good solutions depending on the situation.  I honestly use Vash's solution more often because it easier to maintain "named" things.

Comment: The first class function is something differ ans should not be confused with basis of OO. That concept refer to functional programming.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there's not a wikipedia link to first-class type, which is what i believe we're talking about here.  This stackoverflow page would have been a better reference had I found it the first time around.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599978/what-is-a-first-class-type