# In what programming languages are types treated as values?

Tags: templates, types, programming-languages, zig

[The Zig Programming Language](https://ziglang.org/) promotes the concept that "types are values" which seems like a very powerful concept to me and I wonder what other programming languages support this concept.

I know that for example C++ templates can be used to pass types to a function but types are still different from values in C++.

Comment: This is a really interesting question, but since it doesn't have a single, definitive, factual answer (there are lots of languages that let you work on types in different ways), I suspect that this isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. However, I hope that you get some good answers to help guide you!

Comment: [Idris](https://www.idris-lang.org/) is another statically typed language with first-class types.

Answer (score 5):

Most scripting languages have this, such as: Python, Perl, Ruby, JavaScript, Lua. It's less common with ahead-of-time compiled languages, such as C, C++, Rust, Go.

This feature is commonly called "first-class types", as seen by this other question: [What is a "First Class" type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599978/what-is-a-first-class-type)

Comment: Can you name a few other ahead-of-time compiled languages?